# Cumulative count that starts again when value in column changes (EXCEL)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 4 columns (although only need to know about 3):

**Column A** - An index that counts up from 1 and then resets to 1 after a certain period

**Column B** - A decision Boolean that is '1' for successful and '0' for rejected

The column I need help with is:

**Column C** - What I want is that whilst the index in Column A is counting up, for it to total up (cumulatively) the number of 1s in column B, but then reset when the index in Column A goes back to 1. I have manually started this, but would love a way of doing this automatically through a formula or VBA

Any ideas? I have hosted the data at the following link if anyone could help.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aqd9Lw8Wn3YHgeUPYjb7v5kIeWmq6A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,ROW()))/($A$1:INDEX(A:A,ROW())=1),1)):INDEX(B:B,ROW()))
```

[image]

---

EDIT:

I was way overthinking the above formula use this much simpler formula:

```
=IF(A2=1,B2,C1+B2)
```

[image]

Comment: Scott, that is amazing! Perfect. Thank you! :) I will marks yours as the answer. Really appreciate the time you took to help.

Comment: Ha! Well I was very impressed with the more complicated function (which of course worked).... but yes, I am feeling a little silly myself for not seeing the simpler solution. Thank you once again Scott! :)